# Extracting data from Wikipedia API

Tags: php, json, api, wikipedia

I would like to be able to extract a title and description from Wikipedia using json. So...  wikipedia isn't my problem, I'm new to json and would like to know how to use it. Now I know there are hundreds of tutorials, but I've been working for hours and it just doesn't display anything, heres my code:

```
<?php
  $url="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts|info&exintro&titles=google&format=json&explaintext&redirects&inprop=url";

    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

    $pageid = $data->query->pageids;
    echo $data->query->pages->$pageid->title;
?>
```

Just so it easier to click:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts|info&exintro&titles=google&format=json&explaintext&redirects&inprop=url&indexpageids

I know I've probably just done a tiny thing wrong, but its really bugging me, and the code... I'm used to using xml, and I have pretty much just made the switch, so can you explain it a bit for me and for future visitors, because I'm very confused... Anything you need that I haven't said, just comment it, im sure I can get it, and thanks, in advance!

Comment: Change 'jsonfm' to 'json'.

Comment: It's only jsonfm in the html representation link, not in the code.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right @Joel. I'll change that, thanks.

Comment: oh, I did jsonfm to make it easier to read, doh

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$pageid` was returning an array with one element. If you only want to get the fist one, you should do this:

```
$pageid = $data->query->pageids[0];
```

You were probably getting this warning:

```
 Array to string conversion
```

Full code:

```
    $url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts|info&exintro&titles=google&format=json&explaintext&redirects&inprop=url&indexpageids';

    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = json_decode($json);

    $pageid = $data->query->pageids[0];
    echo $data->query->pages->$pageid->title;
```

Comment: It is the index of the element you want to retrieve from the array. If the array has 3 elements `$demo = array('hi', 'my', 'friend')`, then `$demo[0]` will be `hi`, `$demo[2]` will be `friend` etc. In your case you don't want to retrieve all the array but the only element contained in it. That's why you use the `[0]`.

Comment: thanks for explaining, so it basically gets them by order... ok thanks

Answer (score 5):

I'd do it like this. It supports there being multiple pages in the same call.

```
$url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts|info&exintro&titles=google&format=json&explaintext&redirects&inprop=url";

$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

$titles = array();
foreach ($data['query']['pages'] as $page) {
    $titles[] = $page['title'];
}
var_dump($titles);
/* var_dump returns
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "Google"
}
*/
```

Comment: Helpfull, but I only need it once, +1 for the effort

Answer (score 0):

This code is to extract title and description with the help of Wikipedia api from Wikipedia

```
    <?php
                     
       $url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts|info&exintro&titles=google&format=json&explaintext&redirects&inprop=url&indexpageids';
                
       $json = file_get_contents($url);
       $data = json_decode($json);
                
       $pageid = $data->query->pageids[0];
       $title = $data->query->pages->$pageid->title;
       echo "<b>Title:</b> ".$title."<br>";
       
       $string=$data->query->pages->$pageid->extract;
          
       // to short the length of the string 

       $description = mb_strimwidth($string, 0, 322, '...');
        
       // if you don't want to trim the text use this
           
           /* 
            echo "<b>Description:</b> ".$string;
           */

        echo "<b>Description:</b> ".$description;
     ?>
```