# Retrieve array element from Wikipedia API

Tags: php, arrays, wikipedia-api

I'm having the exact same issue as the author of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17166962/766141 but the answer there isn't working for me.

API Request:

```
$searchQuery = str_replace(" ","+",$value);
$url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts|info&exintro&titles=' . $searchQuery . '&format=json&explaintext&redirects&inprop=url';
$scrape = file_get_contents($url);
```

Approach #1:

```
$data = json_decode($scrape, true);

$pageid = $data->query->pages[0];
echo $data->query->pages->$pageid->canonicalurl;
```

Shows:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

Approach #2:

```
$data = json_decode($scrape, true);

$pageid = $data['query']['pages'][0];
echo $data['query']['pages'][$pageid]['canonicalurl'];
```

Shows:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0
```

When I change the value of `$pageid` to `3395` (which is the page id I'm trying to retrieve data for) - everything works like expected so I'm only having issues with the retrieval of the page id.

Edit:
`print_r($data)` returns:

```
Array ( [batchcomplete] => [query] => Array ( [redirects] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [from] => Buddha [to] => Gautama Buddha ) ) [pages] => Array ( [3395] => Array ( [pageid] => 3395 [ns] => 0 [title] => Gautama Buddha [extract] => Gautama Buddha (c. 563/480 – c. 483/400 BCE), also known as Siddhārtha Gautama, Shakyamuni Buddha, or simply the Buddha, after the title of Buddha, was an ascetic (śramaṇa) and sage, on whose teachings Buddhism was founded. He is believed to have lived and taught mostly in the eastern part of ancient India sometime between the 6th and 4th centuries BCE. Gautama taught a Middle Way between sensual indulgence and the severe asceticism found in the śramaṇa movement common in his region. He later taught throughout other regions of eastern India such as Magadha and Kosala. Gautama is the primary figure in Buddhism. He is believed by Buddhists to be an enlightened teacher who attained full Buddhahood and shared his insights to help sentient beings end rebirth and suffering. Accounts of his life, discourses and monastic rules are believed by Buddhists to have been summarized after his death and memorized by his followers. Various collections of teachings attributed to him were passed down by oral tradition and first committed to writing about 400 years later. In Vaishnava Hinduism, the historic Buddha is considered to be an avatar of the Hindu god Vishnu. Of the ten major avatars of Vishnu, Vaishnavites believe Gautama Buddha to be the ninth and most recent incarnation. [contentmodel] => wikitext [pagelanguage] => en [pagelanguagehtmlcode] => en [pagelanguagedir] => ltr [touched] => 2018-03-31T10:45:06Z [lastrevid] => 833197460 [length] => 109689 [fullurl] => https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gautama_Buddha [editurl] => https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gautama_Buddha&action=edit [canonicalurl] => https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gautama_Buddha ) ) ) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`reset()`](https://php.net/reset) to get the first element of array.

```
$data = json_decode($scrape, true);
$page = reset($data['query']['pages']);
echo $page['canonicalurl'];
```